# Point which do not lie in domain of $f (\frac{2}{x-2})$

Tags: calculus, functions

If $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-17x+66}$$ then the points which are not in the domain of $f (\frac{2}{x-2})$ are:

$(A) \frac{7}{3}$

$(B) \frac{24}{11}$

$(C) \frac{8}{3}$

$(D) 2$

I have already found that $\frac{7}{3}$ and $\frac{24}{11}$ will not be part of domain but I confused about $x=2$

Could someone explain a bit as why or why not $x=2$ will be part of domain?

Comment: It can't be part of the domain because then you will be dividing by 0.

Comment: Your function is $f\circ g$, for $g$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{2}{x-2}$, The composition of $f$ and $g$, $f\circ g$, is only defined for points on which (i) $g$ is defined (i.e., $g(x)$ exists) and (ii) $y=g(x)$ belongs to the domain of $f$ (so that $f(y)$ exists).

Comment: @ClementC. Short and simple yet great explanation. Thank You.